# Setting listener on a Glide image load only captures local variable once

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm using Glide to load an image and I'm setting a new listener on it each time I call it. I expect the anonymous "new RequestListener" to capture the local variable "x" each time, but it only appears to capture it the first time. It's almost like Glide is ignoring my request to set a new listener and reusing the original listener. Here is the code to reproduce it:

```
public void loadImage(int x) {
    GlideApp.with(getContext()).load("http://url.to/image.png").listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) { return false; }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Value of x: " + x);
            return false;
        }
    }).into(imageView);
}
```

Calling loadImage(0) results in:
Value of x: 0

Subsequent calls to loadImage, no matter what value of x I pass in, will always result in:
Value of x: 0

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: is `GlideApp` part of Glide library or is it a wrapper of yours?

Comment: GlideApp is a module / class that gets generated by Glide.

Comment: I see, so from the code it seems that `GlideApp` is not caching the RequestBuilder but it's using the new instance every time, so, are you 100% sure that you're calling the method with values different than 0? did you check with the debugger?

Comment: I tried to made a sample project, from which what I could figure is, when you call `into(imageView);` only the last call is accepted. (I called the function in a for loop. Instead if you call `submit`, it works fine and every time listener is called.

Comment: Yes, If I log x before the Glide call it is the proper value (non-zero). I just proved that it's reusing the old listener by logging "this" in onResourceReady. Is there any way to get it to use the new listener?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @MahmoudAli, It looks like Glide does some magic where it caches and reuses the original listener. I worked around this by having the listener rely on a class instance variable rather than a local variable. That way I can change the value of the variable and the listener will be able to see that change.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today. glide kept using the old listener. It some how caused the same setOnClickListener to keep being used, so basically all my buttons would display the same view. It was fixed once I added:

`.apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))`